# Heat equation with separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

Solve the following Heat equation:

$u_t=u_{xx}, \quad 0<x<1, t>0$

$u(t,0)=1=u(t,1), \quad t\geq 0$

$u(0,x)=1-\sin(\pi x) \quad 0\leq x\leq 1$

What I have tried:

$u(t,x)=T(t)X(x)$

$\Rightarrow T'X=X''T \quad \Rightarrow \space \frac{T'}{T}=\frac{X''}{X}=-\lambda$

1. $T'+\lambda T=0$
2. $X''+\lambda X=0$

solving 1: $T(t)=c_1 e^{-\lambda t}$

solving 2: $X(x)=c_2 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+c_3\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$

with $u(t,0)=1 \quad \Rightarrow \space c_2=1$

Now I don't know what to do with $u(t,1)=1=\cos(\sqrt{\lambda})+c_3\sin(\sqrt{\lambda})$

Comment: You’ll probably want to work with $u := 1 + v$ instead.

Comment: Ah, this means $1+v$ and$\space  v $with$\space v(t,0)=0=v(t,1) \space $and $\space v(0,x)=1+\sin(\pi x)$?

Comment: ok, I get it, thank you